# How to redirect http://example.com to https://example.com in apache2.conf using VirtualHost

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2, virtualhost

I am trying to redirect http URLs to https and also www URLs to non-www.
I am using the latest version of Apache 2 http server running in a Raspberry Pi 3 model B+.

I would like to use VirtualHosts in apache2.conf, because I read in many places that this approach is to be prefered instead of using .htaccess

I get 3 redirects to work OK:

http://www.example.com   goes to https://example.com

https://example.com      goes to https://example.com

https://www.example.com  goes to https://example.com

But
http://example.com       goes to http://example.com

In other words, the non-www unsafe (http) site does not get redirected
to the safe (https) site... and I do not get to load my SSL certificate.

I got the www sites redirected to the non-www using a CNAME.

The http gets to the https using the Redirect directive.

This is the relevant part of my apache2.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
Protocols h2 http/1.1
ErrorLog logs/error_log
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example_com_key.txt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example.com.ca-bundle
SSLUseStapling on
</VirtualHost> 

SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/tmp/stapling_cache(128000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect all of your www websites to non-www and secure them if you have completed the CERTBOT for each domain conf file. Put this in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf inside the Directory /www section:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

There is no need to CERTBOT a www domain after this code is inserted. Just do the domain.com choice. You do not need htaccess files. They can be restricted by the AllowOverride None selection.

Remember to restart apache.